# ADFS in React-Native Apps

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, hybrid-mobile-app, adfs

I am implementing ADFS SSO with web-federation protocol provided by Azure Active Directory in React native. Using https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0 this sample code with auth0 but unable to authorize and get token through this. I’m currently getting an issue with react native. Is there any proper documented example where I can authenticate users of my website through ADFS SSO using react native or native iOS? Any help here would really give a boost to react native implementation for ADFS .

Comment: You may want to describe the problem you are having, as there is no guarantee that example code exists, and even if it does, it may be not helpful in understanding the issue or what you are doing.